# How many letters might Paul have written over his career?

Tags: new-testament, paul-apostle, epistles

How many letters might Paul have written over his 30+ years as an Apostle?  For example, if one expects that he wrote one letter a month, that would suggest 300-400 letters.  I'm curious if there is any informed opinion on this.

Comment: Not an answer, but here is a speculative reply to someone else who wondered: "From what we know of him, we can assume that Paul wrote MANY letters. However, it is apparent that certain letters were written as general letters, to be read in all the churches".   http://evidenceforchristianity.org/did-paul-write-other-letters-what-about-3rd-corinthians/ .  Closely related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/did-paul-write-other-letters-that-are-not-in-the-bible